# how to insert dynamic data from a while loop using ajax in php

Tags: php

I tried inserting the id of the looped users stored in the hidden field using ajax, based on the looped button a user clicks, but it's not working, please can any one help me out?

```
<!----Suggested users Start---->
                    <div class="ms_heading">
                        <h1>Suggested Users</h1>
                    </div>
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                         <?php
                        require '../db.php';
                        $sql = "select * from users order by id desc";
                        //
                       $sql_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query)) {
                           $id = $row['id'];
                           $user_image = $row['profile_img'];
                           $myusername = $row['Username'];
                              ?>

                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="ms_rcnt_box">

                         <div class="ms_pro_img">
                 <img src="User_Images/<?php echo $user_image;?>" alt="" class="img-fluid" id="pro_img"> 
                        </div>
                   <div class="ms_rcnt_box_text">       
    <center><b><a href=""><p><?php if(isset($myusername)){ echo $myusername;}?></p></a></b></center><br/>

                               <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>" id="name">

                               <button type="submit" id="button">SAVE</button>

                        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#button").click(function(){
                    var name=$("#name").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'insert.php',
                        method:'POST',
                        data:{
                            name:name,
                        },
                       success:function(data){
                           alert(data);
                       }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>

                            <?
                             php
                              }
                            ?>
                        </div>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
require '../db.php';
$name=$_POST['name'];
$sql="INSERT INTO `myTest` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, '$name')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "data inserted";
}
else 
{
    echo "failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: "_but it's not working_" is not a very good, if not the worst, error description one can give. What doesn't work? Do you get a blank page? Is data not inserted? Is the wrong data inserted?

Comment: `id`s in HTML must be unique, yours aren't

Comment: As a side comment, your INSERT statement should use either a prepared statement or `mysqli_real_escape_string`, else you are leaving yourself open to a SQL Injection attack. Do yourself  favor and investigate this topic.

Comment: Not whats causing yoru issue but note that you are including the ajax code in your while loop meaning it's aded to each row on the DB thats printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have revised the full html and script code. Please find as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id^=button_]").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var name = $("#name_"+id).val();
        console.log(id+"---"+name);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'insert.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                name: name,
            },
            success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ms_heading"><h1>Suggested Users</h1></div>
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <?php
        require 'db.php';
        $sql = "select * from users order by iUserId desc";
        $sql_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query)) {
            $id = $row['iUserId'];
            $user_image = $row['vImage'];
            $myusername = $row['vFirstName'];
    ?>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="ms_rcnt_box">
                <!-- <div class="ms_pro_img">
                    <img src="User_Images/<?php echo $user_image;?>" alt="" class="img-fluid" id="pro_img">
                </div> -->
                <div class="ms_rcnt_box_text">
                    <center><b><a href=""><p><?php if(isset($myusername)){ echo $myusername;}?></p></a></b></center>
                    <br />
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>" id="name_<?=$id;?>" name="name">
                    <button type="submit" id="button_<?=$id;?>" data-id="<?=$id;?>">SAVE</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. it's now inserting

Comment: Glad to help...!